# Get clean date without any HTML tags

Tags: 7, views, theming, datetime

I am using the Date module together with a view to display dates, and I need to get the date timestamp. The problem is that `$fields['date_in_timestamp']` content comes wrapped in HTML.

```
<span class="date-display-single"> 1468473300 </span>
```

I need only the value and no HTML.

PS: my field "date_in_timestamp" will apply a "U" format for the timestamp.

One possible way I found is described in https://www.drupal.org/node/423870, comment #9. The problem is that this applies to all those who have a certain format, and I don't know how to distinguish them from other similar formats.

Is there any way to get the machine name of the date format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me in this case was easier than I thought.

**Solution**:

In the configurations of the view

1.-
Select settings Style ->
Customize HTML field -> None

- Uncheck Add default classes

2.-
In Rewrite results -> Select Strip HTML tags